# GLEW link error: undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, undefined-reference, glew

When trying to build my graphics project i get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I tried the solution to the other answer, which was `pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3`

I put it in my .sh file but i didnt know where to put it so i put it everywhere and it still didnt work. This is my run.sh file

```
mkdir build
cd build
pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3
cmake ..
pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3
make -j8
pkg-config --static --libs x11 xrandr xi xxf86vm glew glfw3
cd bin
./menger
```

The entire program works on my mac locally but I'm trying to run it on some different environments to see if other ppl can run my project too.  I tried it on my school's linux computers and that was where I got the xconvert selection error.

This is the repo if it helps: https://github.com/amit56/Voyage

By the way, here is my gl3.cmake file, is this the same thing as a build-file?

````
if (APPLE)
         set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/include")
         set(GLEW_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/lib/libGlEW.a")
endif ()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

IF (WIN32)
    find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    LIST(APPEND stdgl_libraries glfw ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
ELSE ()
    FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    #pkg_search_module(GLFW3 REQUIRED glfw3)
        set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/include")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        set(GLFW3_STATIC_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a")
    LIST(APPEND stdgl_libraries ${GLFW3_STATIC_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF ()

message(STATUS "GLEW_LIBRARIES=${GLEW_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "GLFW_LIBRARIES=${GLFW3_STATIC_LIBRARIES}")```
````

Comment: The whole `pkg-config` command you show only lists the libraries. It doesn't actually link with them. You need to modify your build-file to actually link with the libraries.

Comment: is a build-file the same thing the gl3.cmake i edited into my question? Everything works on my own computer, so I'm sure the libraries are being linked somewhere. Is the linking process different in linux compared to mac